# Where is app.js file? What does it mean? in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image][image] [image][image]
[image]

Hello, there is no app.js file in my website, but I keep getting this error and it affects the site. Normally, Google Lighthouse gives information about the problem, but this time Google Lighthouse didn't give the any information. What do you recommend?

Thank you

Comment: Please include code as text in a code block, not as images. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15261914)

Answer (score 1):

`app.js` is the "bundle". It is a concatenation of all your application's files into one.

Try running:

```
npm run build
```

and inspect the files generated at the `/dist` folder.

The files in the `/dist` folders are basically the output webpack produces when it builds your project. `app.js` itself, as said, is a concatenation of all your application's files (those written by yourself and maybe some third-party that you imported), after some transformations performed by plugins and webpack itself.

Comment: i don't have app.js file. How can i create it?

Comment: Run `npm run build`, `app.js` will be automatically generated by vue.

Comment: i did but it didn't work. If you want, i can send a photo about it

Comment: Run `num run build`, and paste your `package.json` in the question. You can paste a picture of the folder structure too

Comment: i added pictures

Comment: Show your folder structure _after_ you run `npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

```
const mysql = require ('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection ({
  hôte: «localhost»,
  utilisateur:'utilisateur',
  mot de passe:'mot de passe',
  base de données:'nom de la base de données'
});
connection.connect ((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log ('Connecté!');
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).